# Is it possible to create a Dapp on top of Bitcoin?

Tags: script, ethereum, decentralization, smartcontracts

Is it possible to create a dapp on top of bitcoin similar to how it can be done with ethereum? Can it be just as capable as ethereum?

Comment: I always thought you couldn't, but in this interview https://youtu.be/AtDCzZwa5Qc Jimmy Song talks about how you can, it's just that Bitcoin's scripting language - Script - is not Turing complete (and can't have loops) like Ethereum's Solidity https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script Maybe someone else can give a more complete answer, though.

Comment: Dapp depends on your definition. And being capable as Ethereum - what does this mean anyhow? Bitcoin is using smart contracts for years, without any security issue(s), so in this sense it is even better than Ethereum, cause noob programmers cannot create million dollar errors. Having said that, it is probably more complicated to use loops and stuff, or bring external data into the blockchain. But that is exactly, what made Ethereum contracts vulnerable (Turing completeness). This is missing in bitcoin and protecting it. So if you need Turing completeness, better stay with Ethereum.